# C# - How to Save and Load a playlist in my MP3 Player?

Tags: c#, winforms, mp3

I'm trying to make my MP3 Player functions work... I need to make it Add songs, Save the current playlist and Load a saved playlist. But I have a problem - each time I load a saved playlist, nothing happens, even I don't know where the problem is, but here's my code:

namespace mp3_player
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    List<Song> songs = new List<Song>();
    string[] files, paths;

    private void btnOpen_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            files = openFileDialog1.SafeFileNames;
            paths = openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                lbSongs.Items.Add(files[i]);
            }
            foreach (string d in open.FileNames)
            {
                lbSongs.Items.Add(d);
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = paths[lbSongs.SelectedIndex];
    }

    private void loadPlaylistToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbSongs.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to clear your songs list?", "Adding...", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                lbSongs.Items.Clear();
                songs.Clear();
            }
        }

        OpenFileDialog openDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openDialog.Filter = "Playlist (*.wpl)|*.wpl";
        if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openDialog.FileName))
            {
                string line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    string path = line;
                    int index = path.LastIndexOf('\\');
                    string name = path.Substring(index + 1);

                    if (!CheckRepeatedSong(path))
                    {
                        songs.Add(new Song(name, path));
                    }
                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
        //RefreshList();
    }
    private bool CheckRepeatedSong(string path)
    {
        bool isExist = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (songs[i].FilePath == path)
            {
                isExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isExist;
    }

    private void savePlaylistToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lbSongs.Items.Count != 0)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveDialog.DefaultExt = ".wpl";
            saveDialog.Filter = "Playlist (*.wpl)|*.wpl";
            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(saveDialog.FileName, false))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < songs.Count; i++)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(songs[i].FilePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addSongsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnOpen_Click_1(sender, e);
    }

}
```

}

I've also made a class 'Song':

```
{
    private string fileName;
    private string filePath;

    public Song() { }
    public Song(string fileName, string filePath)
    {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }
    public string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.fileName;
        }
        set
        {
            this.fileName = value;
        }
    }
    public string FilePath
    {
        get
        {
            return this.filePath;
        }
        set
        {
            this.filePath = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the safed playlist file? Is it like you expect? Did you get an exception when loading the file? Just an info File.ReadAllLines and File.WriteAllLines would make writing and reading the playlists alot easier.

Comment: When saving the playlist and when I try to open it, it shows nothing, the saved playlist is empty...

Comment: Have you debugged into your code? Does the List<Song> songs collection have any items?